# Does $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{3}{n\ln(n)}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I came upon this question while working:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{3}{n\ln(n)}$$

And I was wondering whether it converges or diverges?

A help would be greatly appreciated !

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much @Oily Reynolds

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** By the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), we have that $\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{3}{n\ln n}$ converges if and only if
$\int_2^{+\infty}\frac{3}{x\ln x}dx$ converges. Use substitution for the integral.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Sir , do you know why it starts from n=2 ?

Comment: @lasanmanujitha Because $\ln 1=0$

Comment: lasan. n=1 gives: 1 log (1) = 0 !! in.the denominator. Also look up Cauchy Condensation test.Greetings.

Comment: thank you so much sir @PeterSzilas

Comment: Is the substituitin lnx = y sir ? @rae306

Comment: @lasanmanujitha yes sir, and you will find the thing to be divergent.

Comment: lasan.A pleasure:)

Comment: @lasanmanujitha please accept my answer if you found it helpful ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much , it was helpful , I'm new sorry @rae306

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy condensation test:

$b_n=2^n \dfrac{3}{2^n (n \log 2)}=\left (\dfrac{3}{\log 2}\right )\dfrac{1}{n}$

Hence?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: Thank you sir I learnt a new theory , but I didn't get the part log2, why did you change it?

Comment: manujitha.$ \log (2^n)=n \log 2$.Greetings:)